# Exctract Tag XML without its value xml Shell Script

Tags: xml, bash

Is there a command line command in bash or utility I can use to get a specific tag structure of an xml document without its xhtml ?

```
<country id="2" name="USA">
   <city>NY</city>
   <population>10</population>
</country>
```

I want to get only

```
<country id="2">

</country>
```

Answer (score 1):

`xmlstarlet` to the rescue:

```sh
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m /country -e country -c "@id" -n input.xml
<country id="2">
</country>
```

Except without a newline after the closing `</country>` tag. If that's important to have:

```sh
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m /country -e country -c "@id" -n -t -n input.xml
<country id="2">
</country>
```

Comment: I really wonder how good you are in xmlstarlet, whenever I try to read it's documentation it's not that good and I get discouraged(at least I don't get it that much). Any guidance on good content of it for learning? Or you have any white papers written on it too are welcome too :) thank you cheers for sharing nice answer

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Lots of trial and error combined with a rough knowledge of xslt and xpath.